# Installing Chrome OS Desktop Environment on my 32bit computer

Tags: desktop-environments, 32-bit, chromeos

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65083/what-different-desktop-environments-and-shells-are-available) says that it's possible to install Chrome OS as a desktop environment to Ubuntu but it's only available for 64bit PCs. Would it work on my 32bit PC? I just want to try it. It doesn't need to be perfect. What are the limitations of such an installation?

Comment: it could not be done with 32-bit processor. Just get a cheap 64-bit processor like AMD atlon x2 64

Comment: @grepmaster Or a Core 2 Duo E8500. These are good and cheap (i got one for 35$)

Answer (score -2):

first install 64-bit ubuntu, 32-bit or not

then

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/11/how-to-run-chromeos-in-ubuntu

fix issues by

Google-chrome which is needed to run this build of chromium os must share some features, including sandbox(a hunch). Open Nautilus using sudo power. Browse to filesystem to /opt , there are two folders of our concern chromeos and google. Open google in new tab copy all the contents of /opt/google/chrome folder and paste into /opt/chromeos. nautilus will give you the folder and file conflict notification. MERGE FOLDER BUT SKIP FILES.It will only copy missing files. Now you have chrome-sandbox in chromeos. Now exit and remove the line "--disable-setuid-sandbox /" in chromeos file located in usr/sbin/chromeos if you have edited before. Delete Chrome-os folder in home and start a fresh copy typing chromeos in terminal.

creds to paudelanup

Comment: How exactly do you intend to install 64-bit Ubuntu on a 32-bit computer?

Comment: Installing 64bit software on a 32 bit system will *seriously* mess it up.

Comment: Your solution to installing the Chrome OS DE on a 32 Bit system is installing a 64 Bit system. Nice.